# Combining header and htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

I have the following two snippets:

```
<?php header('Location: example.com/login.php?name='); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo 'Hello' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . ', welcome'; ?>
```

I want to add the htmlspecialchars-encoded name after the `=` in `example.com/login.php?name=` but when I tried to do this, it didn't work.

How would I do this?

Comment: "tried it but didn't work" - what did you try?

Comment: Given that EVERYTHING you'd need to make this happen already exists in your code, exactly what is the mental block keeping you from doing it?

Comment: @noahnu I tried this `<?php header('Location: example.com/login.php?name=htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"])'); ?>`

Comment: Do you understand how the concatenation (merging strings) works in your second code snippet?

Comment: @noahnu No I don't :/

Comment: You mean you want these <?php header('Location: example.com/login.php?name='.'"'.'Hello' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . ', welcome'.'"'.); 
?>

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap No I just want `htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"])` to be behind the `=`

Comment: try these <?php header("Location: example.com/login.php?name=htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'])"); ?>

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell us what you are trying to achieve? It doesn't make sense to put a php function as the value of a query string.

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap nope didn't work :/ just got a HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: put ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); before code and let me know what exactly error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string concatenation; in PHP, you can combine two strings together (concatenate string) with a period (`.`)

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.php?name=' 
           . htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']));
exit();
```

A few other changes that you'll see:

- I added an explicit `exit()` call after I set the Location header; this will cause the redirect to happen without executing any more code, which is frequently undesireable.
- I added a protocol (http, https) to the Location.

Assuming that `$_GET['name'] = 'Mary';`, this would redirect the user to

```
http://www.example.com/login.php?name=Mary
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try it again - with double quotes

```
<?php header("Location: example.com/login.php?name=htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'])"); ?>
```

Comment: I'll try this, thanks